# email html signature scaling images

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2010

have problem with email outlook signature of images which is scalling to bigger sizes, but only in MS outlook 2010.. in new versions everything is ok..

email signature html:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 470px; color: gray; font-family: arial;" width="470px" height="115px">
  <tr>
    <td width="120px">
      <img alt="" src="https://wearemarketing.lt/fez/logo-lt_120d.png" style="margin-left: 4px;" width="120px" height="115px" alt="t" />
    </td>
    <td style="" width="320px">
      <p>
        <span class="name" style="font-size: 14pt;">
                    NAME SURNAME
                </span>
        <br>
        <span class="position" style="font-size: 12pt;">
                        POSITION
                    </span>
        <br />
      </p>
      <p style="font-size: 10pt;">
        <span class="address">
                    ADDRESS
                </span>
        <br>
        <span class="tels">
                        PHONE
                    </span>
        <br>
        <span class="mob">
                            ANOTHER PHOINE
                        </span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="470px">
      <img alt="" src="https://wearemarketing.lt/fez/long-lt_470d.png" style="width: 470px;" width="470px" height="89px" alt="t" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

and is it possible to use not .png, but .svg images?

Comment: hi, you might want to check this out: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ Different mail provider have different engine in interpreting CSS. Some CSS works, some don't. Check out the tables for compatible CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are confusing the formatting of table values for width and height with the way we code CSS values. They are different. In your code you added `px` to when defining heights with tables and images.

**For `<table>`**:

This is correct: `width="200"`

This is incorrect: `width="200px"`

I tested your code with a simple HTML wrapper with my fixes in Litmus and Outlook 2010 and the size now looks roughly the same. I didn't measure.

**SVG Images**:

Outlook, Android and Gmail do not work with SVG images. I suggest sticking with PNG.

Good Luck.

**Working Outlook Footer**:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 470px; color: gray; font-family: arial;" width="470" height="115">
  <tr>
    <td width="120">
      <img alt="" src="https://wearemarketing.lt/fez/logo-lt_120d.png" style="margin-left: 4px;" width="120" height="115" alt="t" />
    </td>
   <td style="" width="320">
      <p>
        <span class="name" style="font-size: 14pt;">
                    NAME SURNAME
               </span>
        <br> 
        <span class="position" style="font-size: 12pt;">
                        POSITION
                    </span>
        <br />
      </p>
      <p style="font-size: 10pt;">
        <span class="address">
                    ADDRESS
                </span>
        <br>
        <span class="tels">
                        PHONE
                    </span>
        <br>
        <span class="mob">
                            ANOTHER PHOINE
                        </span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="470">
      <img alt="" src="https://wearemarketing.lt/fez/long-lt_470d.png" style="width: 470px;" width="470" height="89" alt="t" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: soon I will defenetly try it and actually I was thinking about px and integers in width and height attributes :?